# Reverse a linkedlist in Java

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity

I tried to use recursion to reverse a linkedlist, but I got weird result, the following is my code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by liqiushi on 2/6/14.
 */
public class ReverseLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);

        reverse(list, 0);
        for (int i : list) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    private static void reverse(List<Integer> list, int index) {
        if (list == null)
            return;

        if (index == 5) {
            return;
        }
        int currentVal = list.get(0);
        list = list.subList(1, list.size());
        index += 1;
        reverse(list, index);

        list.add(currentVal);
    }
}
```

the result for the execution is: 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1, where did I get wrong?

P.S. I tried to analyze the time complexity of this algorithm, I think it should be O(n) since it just recurse 4 times, much like a tree in which each node has only one left or right child, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: `subList` returns view which is backed up by original list. If you do something on it, it will also affect original list. Only because you changed local reference `list` to this view, doesn't mean that this changes list to contain only selected elements. To see this take a look at result of `list.subList(1, 2).add(10);`. For now you are only adding elements to this view without removing any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't use `List#add` if you want to **replace** elements (and not **add** them).

You could do the following:

```
private static void reverse(final List<Integer> list, final int index) {
    if (index >= list.size()) {
        return;
    }

    final int currentVal = list.get(index);
    reverse(list, index + 1);
    list.set(list.size() - 1 - index, currentVal);
}
```

Although not being efficient for `LinkedList`s, it will work. :)

---

On the other hand, if you really want your method to work by `add`-ing elements to a new `List`, then it'll have to **return** that `List` and thus, its signature should be:

```
private static List<Integer> reverse(final List<Integer> list, final int index)
```

Basically, in that case, you would:

- **create** and **return** a new `List` when there is nothing left to *reverse*, then
- **recursively reverse** the rest of the given `List` and finally
- **add** the current element at the end of the new `List` before **returning** it.

For example:

```
private static List<Integer> reverse(final List<Integer> list, final int index) {
    if (index >= list.size()) {
        return new LinkedList<>();
    }

    final List<Integer> res = reverse(list, index + 1);
    res.add(list.get(index));
    return res;
}
```

(if you do that, don't forget to iterate over `reverse(list, 0)` and not directly `list` in your `main` method)

---

Just a final point, as @Sundeep pointed out, in this case, using a simple loop would be more efficient - but we believe you actually want to play around with recursion... :)

Comment: it works, thank you. But why do you use final in the parameter and currentVal within the method, why is it better here?

Comment: Actually, I think that this changes nothing in this case. It's just that it makes more sense to me: if I am not going to reassign a variable, I'm declaring it `final`, I believe that this is not a bad habit, though :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to the list that already contains 5 elements. If you don't want the original elements, you should add to a new list.

Comment: Please be careful using blanket statements such as "you shouldn't use xyz where it can be avoided or replaced by zyx". There are many cases where recursion could be replaced with a loop, but would be less efficient or less clear or less maintainable. That being said, this looks like homework.

Comment: @Jason Thanks! Help me here - how would it be less efficient when you can replace it with a loop? I base my statement from the problem of printing 'Fibonnaci series'. It can be easily done using recursion, which is less efficient as the numbers increase. Using a loop is more efficient. Also, a recursion can't always be replaced by a loop. A recursion is a recursion nonetheless.

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing. My point was that saying "you shouldn't use recursion where it can be avoided or replaced by a loop" is a blanket statement, and in reality the decision would depend heavily upon the circumstances and not be a hard and fast rule.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a misunderstanding of the base requirements.

Consider this:  you want to remove all but the last element from the list.  Mutating the list (or sublist) is a bad idea, since what that results in is state not defined by natural recursion.

That said, let's throw out a few things:

- Treat the `List` passed in as `final` - that's to say that you can't reassign to it or modify it safely.
- Deplete the list as you recurse down.  Each slice should be one less than the slice above it.  Return a `List` only containing that slice.
- Don't care about how large the list is, either.  Recursion should be able to work as deep as the call stack will allow you.

That said...consider this:

```
private static <Type> List<Type> listToReverse(int index, final List<Type> list) {
    final List<Type> reversedList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(index == list.size()) {
        return reversedList;
    } else {
        reversedList.addAll(listToReverse(index++, list.subList(index, list.size())));
        reversedList.add(list.get(index - 1));
    }
    return reversedList;
}
```

I intentionally made this generic and left out the public invocation as exercises to the reader.

Bear in mind the base case - if the current "index" location I'm reading is equivalent to the size of the list itself, I've got nothing to do, so I can safely return the empty list.  From there, I then progressively begin adding elements from index 0 to `size - 1`.

E.g. If I make this recursive call with my index starting position at 0, then by the time I've hit the size of my list, I'm adding the element at `size - 1` into the list.

Comment: Just so it makes sense to the reader, I would not use `listToReverse(index++, ... index)` and then `get(index - 1)`, I would rather do `listToReverse(index, ... index + 1)` and then `get(index)`. Also, I wouldn't create a new `List` on each recursive call and then copy in it all the elements returned by the inner call... I would suggest you to have a look at the second implementation given in my answer. Cheers!